# How do I automatically initialize puTTY to top-right of monitor screen with full height?

Tags: windows, windows-7, putty

When I initialize PuTTY, how do I make puTTY automatically position itself to the top right, with full height like this? My PuTTY automatically signs me into the server though.

[image: PuTTY-top-right]

Answer (score 1):

go to putty settings > windows > here set size of window and check the full screen mode. This is all i can help with

Comment: oh and save these setting as default